# An equation of unit vectors

Tags: vectors

Find u, v and w such that all are unit vectors and $\textbf{u} + 2\textbf{v} + \textbf{w} = 0$.

I can guess a solution, but u and w are the same in my solution, of course the problem has not made it explicit that u and w must be different, but I'm not sure if my solution is a good one: u and w = $(cost, sint, 0)$, and v= $(-cost, -sint, 0)$. What are other possible answers? Also another issue is that I've guessed these values for u, w and v, is there a ***way*** to solve such an equation?

Comment: I think your solution is a good one

Comment: I knew I would get this comment :D But my main question is, is guessing the way to solve this equation?

Comment: You're never going to be able to *solve* in the sense you're thinking, since there are infinitely many solutions. But here's a start: What do you know about $\|\mathbf u + \mathbf w\|$? Can you work that out?

Comment: @TedShifrin That would help? u+w=-2v, so ||u+w|| would be ||-2v|| = 2.

Comment: Good. Keep going. I wrote a bit more as a hint in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: If $\mathbf u+\mathbf w$ is twice a unit vector, you should be able to deduce that $\mathbf u\cdot\mathbf w = 1$. Now what does that tell you?

Comment: Yes I could deduce that. This means that they are in the same direction, also both are unit vectors, so they must be equal. Thanks.

Comment: Of course if I may ask a small question too, I had to write a small proof for what you said, but how did you deduce it so fast? From experience, or there's an intuitional relation for ||u+w||=2 => u.w=1 as well?

Comment: Oh, no, it requires proof. Expand $\|\mathbf u+\mathbf w\|^2 = (\mathbf u+\mathbf w)\cdot(\mathbf u+\mathbf w)$. (Alternatively, you have to use the law of cosines, but I prefer the dot product.)

Comment: Great, thanks. I proved it another way, by writing the components and doing the dot product. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, good, but try to avoid writing things out in terms of components unless absolutely necessary. Try to use the power of the linear algebra. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible to find another solution (where $u\ne w$).

Assume all vectors are (pairwise) different. Since $u+2v+w=0$, they form a triangle with sides $|u|=1$, $|2v|=2$ and $|w|=1$. This is not possible unless $u=w=-v$ (in a nondegenerate triangle, the sum of any two sides must be strixctly greater than the other).

Comment: Did you mean $u=w=-v$ (rather than $-2v$)?

Comment: Yes, thanks @J.W.Tanner

Comment: I edited my comment in response to your edit.  And what about $u=w=(0,0,1)$?

Comment: Then $v=(0,0,-1)$

Comment: Isn't that a solution other than OP's?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I guess Tito meant it's not possible to find any solution other than keeping u=w. (Excuse me for interpreting your answer before yourself Tito)

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I tried to man. Sotty if it is not clear.

Comment: You haven't justified the statement "This is not possible," of course. And to @J.W.Tanner, since the three vectors are linearly dependent, there is no loss of generality in working in a plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin edited.